# Writing Assistant is always on top

Tags: palettes, user-interface

Title explains it. Even when I am asking this question on google chrome, Writing assistant is still on the screen.

Comment: Without an actual question, I can only assume that you are happy with this 'feature' and wish to know how to make sure it persists ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Palettes have the setting [`WindowFloating -> True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindowFloating.html) which causes them to float above other windows *inside* Mathematica, but these should not persist when focus is given to another application.  However in my experience palettes occasionally become momentarily "stuck" on top but simply switching focus an extra time or two usually fixes it.  If this is unsuccessful restarting *Mathematica* has never failed to fix it.  If you have a persistent always-on-top palette that survives a restart and focus changes please give the details of your version and operating system.